# DB2 insertion into a table with identity column

Tags: db2, primary-key, sql-insert

I'm currently trying to automate a DB2 database through shell scripts but there seems to be a problem with the INSERT operation.

The tables I create look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "TRAINING1"
(ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (STARTS WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
F1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_train1_id primary key(ID));
```

Now the creation works just fine for all similar tables, but when I attempt to insert data:

```
db2 "insert into TRAINING1 values ('hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar')"
```

I get this error:

```
SQL0117N The number of values assigned is not the same as the number 
of specified or implied columns or variables. SQLSTATE=42802
```

As far as I understand, the primary key I specified should generate values automatically and cannot have values explicitly assigned to it. Out of curiosity I did this:

```
db2 "insert into TRAINING1 values (1, 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar')"
```

and it then complains with this error:

```
SQL0798N A value cannot be specified for column "ID" which is defined 
as GENERATED ALWAYS. SQLSTATE=428C9
```

I'm still fairly new to DB2 but almost a week later, I still haven't found any solutions to this yet.
I'm running DB2 Express Edition on a 64-bit Ubuntu virtual machine.
Any thoughts on why it's doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You list 4 character columns for the `INSERT`, but there's only 3 character columns in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to skip over a column in an `INSERT` statement, you must specify the columns that are not to be skipped:

`db2 "insert into TRAINING1 (f1, name, surname) values ('hello', 'world', 'foo')"`

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be intuitive, though? With many other SQL applications it isn't necessary to explicitly list the columns to fill. Is DB2 different in this way?

Comment: @ZenadiaGroenewald - If you don't list the columns, how is it supposed to know which ones you want filled?  Even when you supply all columns, which columns actually get filled might surprise you - if you add a new column in the middle somewhere, and the types are still compatible, data may end up in strange places.  You're supposed to _always_ list columns for an insert, even when you give all of them, to avoid any such surprises.